# List of chatrooms

Tags: discussion, chat

This is a place where we could collect list of chat rooms associated with this site. There are several rooms which have potential to be useful if more users were aware of them or more users visited them. Collecting a list of such rooms here could increase their visibility. This was previously discussed on meta and gained some support: [Would list of chat rooms (and chat room suggestions) be useful?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26649)

If you have some chat room which is meant to be "public" and "for the long run", please add it as an answer. (I.e., rooms worth adding here are the rooms which are not created to deal with a single problem or to continue a specific conversation about and particular problem).

In particular, we could list rooms:

- [Devoted to specific area of mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26814/list-of-chatrooms/26817#26817)
- [Reading groups and study groups](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26814/list-of-chatrooms/26819#26819)
- [Administrative and janitorial rooms](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26814/list-of-chatrooms/26816#26816) (related to site moderating and maintenance rather than to some mathematical topics)

Of course, if some room deserves to be described in more detail in a separate answer, do not hesitate to add it.

Comment: Should we made a separate entry for the main chat room? Should we also list some rooms from other sites which are "close" to mathematics?

Comment: Are you suggesting that this question be the list or that such a list be created. While the first is a good idea, I wonder how it would be kept up-to-date and whether it would become unwieldy and inefficient to use over time. It would seem best if we could create a special page which is designed to be easy to review and keep up-to-date.

Comment: A post on MathOverflow Meta somewhat similar to this one: [Specialized chat rooms](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/355).

Answer (score 16):

**Areas of mathematics**

Let us list here rooms which serve for discussions related to a specific area of mathematics.

- [Basic Mathematics](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77161/basic-mathematics) is meant for all basic mathematical discussion, including basic logical reasoning, simple properties about natural/rational/real/complex numbers, induction/recursion, elementary combinatorics, synthetic geometry, ...
- [Calculus and analysis](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/14150/calculus-and-analysis) is a room which is intended for all areas which broadly fall under analysis (calculus, real analysis, functional analysis, complex analysis, ...). (Some of these areas had separate rooms in the past, but they did not generate enough interest.)
- [Category theory](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/68360)
- [Differentiable Manifolds](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73238/differentiable-manifolds) - this room is intended for discussing anything related to Manifold theory, Differential geometry.
- [Dynamical Systems and Chaos Theory](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55403/dynamical-systems-and-chaos-theory) - this room is intended to have discussion on Differential equations, Dynamical systems, Non Linear Dynamics, Chaotic systems, Chaos theory.
- [General Topology](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/15201/general-topology)
- [Geometry & Topology](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/20807/geometry-topology) is a room for discussions various areas related to geometry and topology (algebraic topology and differential topology, differential geometry, homological algebra, homotopy theory, ...) Originally some of these areas had separate rooms which were used only by a few users - you can find pointers to discussions about creating a single room [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20807/conversation/expanding-scope-of-the-room) and [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20807/conversation/expanding-scope-of-the-room-more-links).
- [Group Theory](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80888/group-theory) - this room is intended for discussion of group theory.
- [Linear & Abstract algebra](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/13473/linear-abstract-algebra) - as the name of the room suggests, this is for discussion of topics from linear algebra and abstract algebra.
- [Linear algebra](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/75088/linear-algebra) - now also a separate room for linear algebra was created, so far it has not gained much attention.
- [Logic](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic) is meant for any discussion about mathematical logic, including foundations (including philosophy/ontology of mathematics and type/set theories), deductive systems, proof theory, reverse mathematics, computability theory, model theory, ...
- [Modern abstract analysis](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/19167) (Originally started as functional analysis chatroom, later expanded to include topics from measure theory, harmonic analysis, more advanced topic from real analysis and other related areas.)
- [Number Theory](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/12070/number-theory)
- [Probability and Statistics](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65689/probability-and-statistics)-is meant for any discussion on Probability theory and Statistics.
- [Set Theory](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2318/set-theory) - this room is intended for anything related to set theory.

Answer (score 12):

**General discussion rooms**

- [Mathematics](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) − The main chat-room for Mathematics SE, for both general discussion & math questions alike. Just ask. Also keep in mind: [Main Chatroom Guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3890).
- [Math Meta](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64952/math-meta-chat) − The main chat-room for Mathematics Meta stuff. Basically whatever you want to discuss on Math Meta or about Math Meta is on-topic here.

For specific areas of mathematics, try [the dedicated chat-rooms](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26817).

---

**Administrative rooms (for moderating and maintaining the site)**

- [CURED](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/cured) − The acronym stands for Close/Undelete/Reopen/Edit/Delete. Sometimes the review queues and other tools are not sufficient or specific actions need more discussion. This room is for such cases and related discussions. SmokeDetector (a bot for detecting spam posts) also posts its messages in this room.
- [Tagging](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/3740/tagging) − This room is intended for discussions on which tags should or should not be created or deleted and also for discussion about (re)tagging specific questions.
- [Boulevard of Broken Links](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135583/boulevard-of-broken-links) − For reporting and triaging of broken links.  Sometimes a link is broken for systematic reasons (domain reorganization) and sometimes for idiosyncratic reasons (sites unmaintained).

For moderator-related stuff go to the [Math Mods' Office](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26815) instead.

Comment: How long has the room called C.R.U.D.E. existed?

Comment: @MichaelHardy As you can see [from the transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2165/2012/1/11), it was created in January 2012.

Comment: So, CRUDE is now operating under an assumed name?

Comment: Apparently, @Gerry. [I may have coined the alternative order of letters](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28390/11619) in a comment. But I think it is still premature to change the name.

Answer (score 9):

[Math Mods' Office](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/20352/math-mods-office) is a room which has a specific purpose and is intended mainly to things where the input of moderators might be relevant. Creating this room was announced in [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19265#19316) and the room description is

> For informal chat with the site moderators about moderation, spam, troublesome users and other issues you need ♦ input on.

Answer (score 7):

The [The Crusade of Answers](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141/the-crusade-of-answers) is a room for discussion and resolution of old, unanswered questions. Sometimes users link to easily-answerable (but unanswered) questions for others, or link to answers that perhaps deserve a vote but went unnoticed.

There is an Unanswered Tracker Feed in the room that indicates the change in the number of unanswered questions from day to day.

Answer (score 6):

[In the search of a question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/46148/in-the-search-of-a-question) - this room was created partly to collect feedback on Approach0 search engine and partly to assist with searching on the site in general. The creation of the room was mentioned here: [Announcing a third-party search engine for Math StackExchange](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24978).

Answer (score 5):

[In praise of Math.SE site and its users](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/17403/in-praise-of-math-se-site-and-its-users) - this room was started as a reaction to discussions on meta saying that congratulatory post are no longer welcome on meta (or at least some part of users does not like them). See, for example, this meta discussion: [Are congratulatory posts off-topic on meta? Or only some of them?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16881) Some brief description of the purpose of the room is also given at the [beginning of the room transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/17403/2014/9/24). In short, this room is a good place to go:

- If you want to congratulate some user to an achievement on this site.
- If you have some interesting statistic related to this site which is worth sharing.

If you look at the [starred messages](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/17403/in-praise-of-math-se-site-and-its-users?tab=stars) from this room, you can get rough idea what kind of messages was posted here in the past (and also which of them were considered interesting by the users - enough to getting starred).

Answer (score 4):

**Reading groups and study groups**

Let us collect here rooms which are intended to assist a group of users studying specific text or specific topic.

- <s>[Set Theory Study Group](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/62628/set-theory-study-group) - the intention is first to go through necessary preliminaries and then to study [Kunen's Set Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_Theory:_An_Introduction_to_Independence_Proofs) (the newer edition).</s> This group was eventually abandoned.
- As of 7/26/2022, there is a new [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138052/advanced-set-theory-study-group) created with the goal of organizing an advanced set theory study group. The room is called [Advanced Set Theory Study Group](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/138052/advanced-set-theory-study-group).

The following two rooms are now frozen - after a longer period of inactivity. Of course, if there is interest to use such rooms again, we might ask the moderators to unfreeze. <s>There are two rooms which are intended as places where people might find other users interested in a specific topic:</s>

- [Find your Math Partner](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113060/conversation/the-guideline)
- [Find your Physics Partner](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113061/conversation/the-guideline)

Comment: It is probable that some reading/study groups will eventually come to an end. (Some of them successfully, some of them less so.) It might perhaps still be useful to keep them listed here even after that (perhaps in a separate section of this answer) - they might serve for users interested in the same topic. And perhaps for people contemplating starting such a group here, looking at similar past undertakings might help to see what to expect or which mistakes to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

**Calculus?**

[Simply Beautiful Art's realm of calculus and analysis](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54911/simply-beautiful-arts-realm-of-calculus-and-analysis)

> where you may feel free to do your calculus

But calculus isn't really the only thing that happens there. Random chat about my large numbers and a whole bunch of other stuff happens in there.

Comment: I am curious as to what the downvote is supposed to signify. Just... curious.

Comment: I'll add that in the meantime [the room has been frozen](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/54911/2018/4/11).

Comment: Indeed, and is now closed, @MartinSleziak.  It seems that SBA is now a room owner in the topic room (see above, already listed, Calculus and Analysis.)

Answer (score 2):

[**Philosophy of Mathematics**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65129/philosophy-of-mathematics)

> This room is intended for discussing Philosophy of Mathematics. For an elaboration of what I mean by "Philosophy of Mathematics" see [this](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/philosophy-mathematics/). ...

I think I should mention here that the aim of this room shouldn't be confused with the [Logic](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic) room simply because even though Logic is an important part of Philosophy of Mathematics, it is only a *part* and Philosophy of Mathematics has several other concerns which is difficult to characterize as purely logical (in the formal sense of the term).

Comment: Let me say for the record that I was originally an owner of this room but stopped participating after user170039 refused to let me call a true crank a crank. That is all I shall say here, but anyone is free to ask me for details.

Comment: This room was eventually [frozen](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/65129/2019/9/16).

Answer (score 2):

Rooms related to [bounties](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bounty/info) and [hot network questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hot-questions-list):

- [Pearl Dive](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/102837) - see: [Launching *Pearl Dive* - a chatroom where excellent questions/answers meet willing sponsors](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31105)
- [Hot and bountied questions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/106623) - this room is intended for listing HNQs and bounties, to make them easier to find. (And possibly for some discussions about them.)