# Why the chat rooms are created?

Tags: discussion, chat

I have reading a book myself; more than 90 % of the book is ok to me; but I have some problems on it. Is it ok to ask my questions in a related chat-room? Because I believe that they are so easy, and it seems shameful to me to ask such an absurd question?

Comment: if there is an related chatroom you can definitely ask there. But very very few MSE users visit chat rooms, so your questions might be unnoticed.

Comment: Maybe reasonable places could be the main chatroom or the room specific to the area of mathematics you are reading about (if there is such room). See here: [List of chatrooms](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26814).

Comment: I'll just add that the title of your question and the body seem (at least to me) as completely different questions.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak ; yes you are right. I mean : "for example; as one of purpose of the chatrooms; Is it ok to ask questions in chat rooms? Is it one of their capacities?". May be It is better to modify the title.

Comment: The chatrooms are where *extended discussion* in the comment section goes to die.

Comment: "*Because I believe that they are so easy, and it seems shameful to me to ask such an absurd question?*" but what you believe ≠ what *others* believe... it might be possible that your question is way beyond my knowledge instead. Moreover, why don't you feel ashame asking that in the chat (honest curiosity)? (Of course, there's nothing wrong asking a question in the chat, though you might even get prompted to also post it on the main site)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, one of the functions of the chatrooms is to allow discussion of problems in a "chatty" fashion that is not appropriate to the Q&A style of main Math.SE.  Back and forth discussions often start in the Comment section of a Question and get migrated to Chat.

Comment: I agree, though it is best to ask in a chatroom suggesting it deals with the topic of the chatroom.  Mathematics (chat) is available to all for pretty much all questions; but there are also chatrooms for logic, calculus, real analysis, algebra, set theory, and much more. And from what I've seen over a half dozen years is that many many users have found their participation in a chat or two, or more, pretty satisfying.

Answer (score -2):

I frequently have this same problem but I have learnt to ask the question anyway. Provided the question or equivalent doesn't already exist, often the answer is given in a comment rather than an answer, as users are embarrassed to answer such trivial questions. But inevitably somebody later needs an answer to the same question and finds it useful. In fact I now see many others asking relatively trivial questions.

MSE is for mathematicians of all levels and there are as many trivial misconceptions and problems understanding as there are deep and interesting ones.  While we of course aspire not to ask bad questions, bad or duplicate question will get downvoted and removed so you receive feedback from the community on what is considered acceptable.

I get the impression some of the more advanced mathematicians fail to appreciate the full extent of my mathematical ineptitude and find trivial questions frustrating but there are other less experienced mathematicians who know more than me while appreciating my difficulty with simple problems and are happy to help.