# How to decide in which math chat room to post a link to my math-related question?

Tags: discussion, support, chat

While some sites have only a few chat rooms, this one has quite a few even excluding those that are for single individuals or discussions moved from comments.

How can I decide which chat room (if any) would be appropriate for mentioning my question [Can Lissajous orbits have stable/unstable manifolds?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30175/12102) which while on a different site, is math-based?

I'm not a mathematician, so I don't have any intuition into which topic or category of mathematics this would fall under, so I can't even venture a guess.

Comment: I don't think that you can go wrong by asking in [Mathematics](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics).  If there is a better place, the folk there might be able to help you find it.

Comment: @XanderHenderson done, thanks! Still I'm interested in exploring the more general form of this question. I wonder if an "ask here first" label or even an object at the top of the list of rooms page might be a good idea, so thinking of formulating a general SE meta question, and of course searching for an existing one first.

Comment: In case it is helpful, here on meta we have: [List of chatrooms](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26814).

Comment: @MartinSleziak excellent, I think that is in fact the answer to this question, shall we just mark this a duplicate of that? Anything that would increase that answer's visibility would be a plus.

Comment: I would not be too hasty in closing as a duplicate - I can imagine that somebody posts here some advice about using chat. In my opinion, the two question are not *exactly* the same, although they are related. But if for some time nobody answers and you still think that closing as a duplicate is the way to go, it can be done.

Comment: Since you mentioned visibility of that post - it is shown among linked questions (in the sidebar on the right) for several questions; at the moment [there is 18 of them](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/26814). I'd say that this adds to a visibility of that post.