# How to link a duplicate post to two different posts where there are answers?

Tags: support, exact-duplicates, linked-questions

Recently I've asked this question on MSE which has in fact two questions on it:

[Describe all $R$-modules of low order (up to isomorphism)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3522336/describe-all-r-modules-of-low-order-up-to-isomorphism)

Later, I realized that in two different posts there were answers that solve my questions, namely [$\Bbb F_2[X]$ modules with 8 elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1948774/bbb-f-2x-modules-with-8-elements?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Isomorphism classes of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ modules.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1405419/isomorphism-classes-of-mathbbzi-modules?rq=1)

I flagged my post as a duplicate of the first one and they were linked each other but I didn't know how to link to the other post. Can I do this or it isn't an action valid? I hope I'm being clear with the question.

Thanks!

Comment: A question can only be closed as a duplicate of one other question, but gold badge holders in one of the tags and moderators can edit the duplicate list to add more duplicates (or replace a bad duplicate with a better one). Would you like me to close it as a duplicate and edit both questions you linked here in the dupe list?

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks, Yes it would be fine.

Comment: Done. And in what I wrote above I've forgotten that when a question is closed as a duplicate by the votes of several users, then those users can have chosen different duplicate targets, and then those different targets are in the list from the start. But that doesn't work with single-vote closures, like when you mark your own question, have a gold badge in the tag, or are a moderator, each user can only select one target.

Comment: Also, anyone can add a link to another MSE page, either in the question, the answer, or comments.  All of those problems show up in a "Linked" list on the right hand side of the page.

Comment: Some topics related to duplicates are also discussed in [CRUDE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2165/crude) - so if the question has not been closed yet, you could also asked there whether somebody would be willing add another duplicate target. (You can find a brief description of this room in the [List of chatrooms](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26814). You can find some past discussion if you search for [duplicate](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=duplicate&room=2165) or [duplicates](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=duplicates&room=2165) in the room.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When voting to close a question as a duplicate, every user can select only one duplicate target.

But users with a gold badge in one of the tags and moderators can edit the duplicate list — add more targets, replace targets, or remove targets, as appropriate.

So for the time being, you cannot add another target to the list yourself, but when appropriate you can request that somebody else adds it. (Flag for moderator attention, along the lines of "Please add [link to target] to the list of duplicate targets".)