# Are questions which ask for references to other questions, legal?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I was wondering if I could ask for references for a particular type of questions from MSE. Is it legal?

For example, if I wanted references of questions which were related to proving $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a^n}{n!}=0$. (I had come across quite a lot of such types.)

There are many questions (a few of them [duplicate]s) that answer the question. But when we look at the answers to all those questions, we get to understand the different approaches to the same question. With every new answer to such type of question, we get to know something new. Sometimes these questions are not marked as duplicates due to slight change in the phrasing or different questions with exactly the same underlying concepts.

Comment: Normally, you would be able to use [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/), but the site is down until May 12. The tag [reference-request] exists but this is mostly used for references to books or journal articles since you could use Approach0. If your question isn't urgent, I would advise you to wait.

Comment: Would you clarify what you by "reference of questions"? Do you mean simply links to such question? (The word [reference](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reference) might refer to something like the book where the problem/solution comes from, to mention just one possible meaning.)

Comment: @TobyMak Until Approach0 is back, one might try [SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=$%7B%5Clim_%7Bn%5Crightarrow%20%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Ba%5En%7D%7Bn!%7D%7D$) - and probably there are also some other similar search engines that I am not aware of. (Or one could try some other tricks [which are useful when searching](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265).)

Comment: @Martin simply links.

Comment: Maybe not all of them are among the duplicates. But in the case you listed as an example, one has to wonder whether [the 20 answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/77550) and [the 64 links](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/77550) which are offered among the [meta-tag:linked-questions] aren't already enough.

Comment: @MartinSleziak. Thanks for mentioning SearchOnMath. But sometimes two questions with a similar concept have different names, hence search engines cannot comprehend.

Comment: @MartinSleziak It was just an example I thought of. I just wanted to know whether such questions are legal.

Comment: Re: *have different names, hence search engines cannot comprehend.* Maybe one possible strategy in such cases might be asking [in the main chatroom](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26814/list-of-chatrooms/26816#26816) or in the [chatroom devoted specifically to searching](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26814/list-of-chatrooms/26818#26818).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not really an answer to the question whether this type of questions would be on-topic. But I still wanted to add some useful pointers in an answer rather than leaving them just in comments.

- The software automatically creates [various list of questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29265/how-to-search-on-this-site/29269#29269). In the situation you describe, you might look mainly on the [linked questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linked-questions). For the topic you mentioned this leads to [64 questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/77550) (and the question [already has 15 answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/77550), if we also count deleted ones, there are 5 answers). Of course, you might some other posts on this topic which are not linked there.
- In particular, when searching formulas, you might try various search engines designed specifically for this purpose. You can find links to some of them and some other advice pertaining to searching in this post: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)
- If you cannot find a post relevant to the topic you're interested in, some places where you can ask for help are [the main chatroom](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26814/list-of-chatrooms/26816#26816) or the  [chatroom devoted to searching](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26814/list-of-chatrooms/26818#26818).