# How to correct a duplicate flag?

Tags: support, closing, flagging, exact-duplicates

I initially flagged [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268158) as a duplicate of another question, but then realized the other question was not exactly a duplicate. I then found a better (exact) duplicate, and tried to correct the original flag.

The system did not allow me to flag as a duplicate again, as the original question was already flagged as a duplicate.  So I unflagged the question, so far so good.  I was then thinking it would allow me to reflag the question as a duplicate again.  But somehow it does not, saying "you have retracted your recommended closure flag".

I eventually deleted the automatically added flagging comment and manually added a comment mentioning the better duplicate.

Is there a way to adjust a mistaken duplicate flag?

Comment: I think that both close votes and flags can be re-cast after 14 days, see [Age close votes after 14 days, regardless of views, allowing recasting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223) and the [questions linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/250223). (Perhaps somebody is able to confirm whether this is the case for the retracted flags too.) If you want to do that without waiting, the natural thing to do is to ask other users for help. (In a comment or in [a suitable chatroom](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26814/list-of-chatrooms/26816#26816).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak It seems that close votes and flags can be re-cast after 14 days only if they happen to *age away*. It seems that if a flag is *retracted*, then one can't reflag it. I believe the same holds for closure votes as well, but this doesn't seem to be clearly spelled out anywhere on [meta.se]. A couple of posts there that I found to be relevant: [Re-flagging an unflagged question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283585/986753) and [Change the reason of a flag to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349500/986753).

Comment: I've had this happen before and unless you have a gold tag badge and the accompanying [dupehammer powers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links), I think your best bet is probably to go visit CURED if you want to close the question as a duplicate. I would really like the ability to make the changes to duplicate flags you're after, but I suspect that sort of thing would take some effort on global meta to address and cannot be handled locally on math.meta.